# A function of type: ('a -> ('b -> 'c)) -> ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'c) in Standard ML

Tags: functional-programming, polymorphism, sml, polyml

Whilst revising for my programming languages exam, there are a few type inference questions for the Standard ML section, I can do most of them by doing type inference in my head, and I'm quite good at it, however there is one question that leaves me stumped.

I have to write a function of type:

***('a -> ('b -> 'c)) -> ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'c)***

So in my head I should have a function with two arguments that are functions, f and g. Both would take an argument, x, but I cannot add that argument x into this function as it only takes two arguments, so I am left to create this function using the o operator, for pipe-lining functions.

So f takes an argument, and returns a function
g takes an argument, and returns a value.
Then the overall function takes a value and returns a value.

I'm not sure how I can apply f and g using only the o operator to imply those rules.

Any help would be extremely appreciated :)
Thanks, Ciaran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned, you need to write a function of two arguments:

```
fun my_function f g = body
```

where `f : 'a -> 'b -> 'c` and `g : 'a -> 'b` and `body : 'a -> 'c`.

Since `body` has type `'a -> 'c`, we can write it as

```
body = fn x => body'
```

where `body'` has type `'c` and `x : 'a`.

Observe, that `f x : 'b -> 'c` and `g x : 'b`, and if you have a function of type `'b -> 'c` and a value of type `'b` it's easy to construct a value of type `'c` by applying the function to the argument: `(f x) (g x)`.

The above gives us:

```
fun my_function f g = fn x => (f x) (g x)
```

or, alternatively, moving `x` to the left-hand side of the definition we get:

```
fun my_function f g x = f x (g x)
```

By the way, if you are familiar with [combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic), then you could notice that the resulting function represents the `S` combinator.

Comment: This is brilliant!
Thank you so much, very useful and has changed the way I think about these questions, cheers.

Comment: Glad to help :)